# How to get access token from Spotify's Web API using PKCE flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, asynchronous, spotify

I have a front-end, single-page react application and so I'm using PKCE flow for Spotify's authorization.

I have an object titled Spotify and within it, I have two methods:
`login()`,
`getAccessToken()`

when I make a call to the `login()` method, I am redirected to Spotify's login page where I log in, and then am redirected back to my application. However, when I made a call to the `getAccessToken()` method, I get a 400 error in my console.

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here and have followed [Spotify's guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-pkce-flow) for the PKCE flow. I have been working on this for days and still cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my Spotify object which includes both `login()` and `getAccessToken()` methods:

```
const Spotify = {
    login() {
        let codeVerifier = generateRandomString(128);

        generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier).then(codeChallenge => {
          let state = generateRandomString(16);
          let scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email';

          localStorage.setItem('code-verifier', codeVerifier);

          let args = new URLSearchParams({
            response_type: 'code',
            client_id: clientId,
            scope: scope,
            redirect_uri: redirectUri,
            state: state,
            code_challenge_method: 'S256',
            code_challenge: codeChallenge
          });

          window.location = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' + args;
        });
    },
    
    getAccessToken() {
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
      let code = urlParams.get('code');

      let codeVerifier = localStorage.getItem('code_verifier');

      let body = new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
        client_id: clientId,
        code_verifier: codeVerifier
      });

      fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          },
        body: body
        })
        .then(response => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('HTTP status ' + response.status);
          }
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          localStorage.setItem('access-token', data.access_token);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
        });  
    }
```

Within these methods, they make calls to a `generateRandomString(length)` and `generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier)` functions which I also have written out (not shown in the code above). I copied them directly from Spotify's PKCE guide which I have linked above.

the clientId and redirectUri are specific to my app and hence also not shown.

Answer (score -1):

I'm also a beginner in Front-End, so do not take my words for granted. I ran into something similar other day, I was also trying to call Spotify's API and for some reason my state variable was not responding as it should, nothing was getting saved.

After a small session of debugging and documentation reading I found out this:

> In development, you will see two fetches in the Network tab.

Source: [React Documentation Fetch Data with Effects](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#fetching-data)

This double fetching was returning as a 400 on the second time, since Spotify's API only allow you to verify a random code once. The 400 result was getting parsed into my code and changing the access token value from the correct one to a null value, this simple solution did the trick for me:

```
    useEffect(() => {
  let ignore = false;

  async function startFetching() {
    const json = await fetchTodos(userId);
    if (!ignore) {
      setTodos(json);
    }
  }

  startFetching();

  return () => {
    ignore = true;
  };
}, [userId]);
```

Also I don't know if it might suit you, but [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/) was really helpful to me.

Best regards!